# problema con Flutter en Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, flutter, dart

estoy instalando flutter en ubuntu, segui todos los pasos de la documentacion de la pagina oficial.

al ejecutar

```
$ flutter doctor 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale es_BO.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

como pueden ver tengo ese error y ejecuto lo que me dese el asistente de flutter. y me sale este error.

```
    $ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

me pueden ayudar a solucionar este problema por favor, gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Mira si tienes el Android SDK Command-line Tools, Android SDK Command-line Tools si deseas mas ayuda puedes ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error